# How to copy work item id in TFS?

Tags: tfs

I constantly need to copy only the id of the work item, but in VS2010, I could not find an easy way to do that. The nearest thing I find is that I can select an item in the query result grid and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to copy info and then extract only work item id. Any other easier way? An extension that does just that would be lovely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the work item open, you should be able to get it by making a macro which copies DTE.ActiveDocument.Name to the clipboard.

Comment: VS 2012 removed macros.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

On the query, right click on the work item, Copy Work Item shortcut. You will be able to copy and paste the work item id and the Title.